# Is there a way to extract contact information from a google group?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-groups

I have a script which pulls all the email addresses from a google group.

I need to extract the Full name associated with each email address, this information is stored in the contacts app.

It looks like I can only extract email addresses and role information from groups, is there a way to then link this information to the contacts app to extract their Full Names?

It's worth noting that I don't have admin access so can't use Admin SDK

This is the script I'm using to get the email addresses:

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "email@emailcom";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  var users = group.getUsers();
    var str = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length +
  " members: ";
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    str = str + user.getEmail() + ", ";
  }
  Logger.log(str);
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setValue(str)
  }
```

I'm thinking of then connecting with a script like this, but can't seem to get it to work on a list of email addresses in a range on my sheet even if I split it out

```
function getUserName(){
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(query);
for (var i in contacts) {
  Logger.log(contacts[i].getFullName());
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm far from an expert on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can connect Google Groups and ContactApp directly, without storing the email addresses in the spreadsheet

Sample

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "email@emailcom";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var str = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length +
  " members: ";
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var email = user.getEmail();
    var contact =  ContactsApp.getContact(email);
    if(contact!=null){
      Logger.log(contact.getFullName());
      str=str+contact.getFullName()+" ";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry - hope you can help again! How would I then set these values in a column on my sheet, I can't seem to get it to register the results as a string to use (even when using JSON.stringify) and keep getting this error: "Cannot find method setValues(string)" any help appreciated!

Comment: The result of `contact.getFullName()` is a string already. I just modified my answer to see how you can add the results to your already existing string.